# Java- Getting unexpected type error when declaring new generic set

Tags: java, generics

I thought I knew what I was doing with generics, but apparently not.

```
ArraySetList<char> setA = new ArraySetList<char>();
```

When compiled gives:

```
error: unexpected type
ArraySetList<char> setA = new ArraySetList<char>();
             ^
required: reference
found:    char
```

As well as the same error for all subsequent char's. I'm wondering how to declare a new ArraySetList of characters.

Here are all my files.

```
http://pastebin.com/4h37Xvu4     // ArraySetList (extends ArrayUnsortedList)
http://pastebin.com/FxmynzkC     // Driver
http://pastebin.com/CgVA0zjY     //ArrayUnsortedList (implements ListInterface)
http://pastebin.com/3iXrCsCc     //ListInterface\
```

Comment: Actual type parameters may not be primitive types, only reference types.  Thus, the expression `ArraySetList<char>` is an invalid type.

Comment: @scottb Excellent answer, don't post it as a comment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Java Generics work for objects and not for primitive data types. If you, however, need to store primitive data types, you will need to use their corresponding wrapper class objects.
These classes just "wrap" around the primitive data type to give them an object appearance.

For `char`, the corresponding wrapper class is `Character` and hence, you must write your line of code as so:

```
ArraySetList<Character> setA = new ArraySetList<Character>();
```

Please read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html

When you add elements, however, you will add normal `char`. That is because Java will automatically convert it into `Character` for you and back to `char` *automatically*, if need be. This is called auto-boxing conversion.

> Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes
>   between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper
>   classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a
>   Double, and so on. If the conversion goes the other way, this is
>   called unboxing.

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Imo, manually box everything yourself.  Autoboxing can lead to some peculiar and hard-to-track errors.  If you do your own boxing, you remain in control.

Comment: True. Good advise. I didn't know that it could possibly lead to issues.

Comment: Why are arraylists different?

Answer (score 8):

Generic type arguments require reference types (or wilcards).

You can't use primitive types (for more see [restrictions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html));

```
ArraySetList<Character> setA = new ArraySetList<Character>();
```

Read [JLS 4.5.1 Type Arguments and Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) for usable types

Comment: `Producer Extends Consumer Super`. I must point that out to avoid future problems ;)